# sed number between special characters

Tags: shell, sed

I need to get a number string from between two special strings.

String : *Build : 76.x-20161016_x_567.0 <br> GRN : <a href="http://toolserver.lab.net:9080/jenkins/job/test_prj/20/changes">109960</a>*

Need to get the number (here 109960) between ">" and "</a>"
How can I use sed for this.?

Comment: This is pretty straight forward. What did you try?

Comment: String is `<description>Build : 76.x-20161016_x_567.0 <br> GRN : <a href="http://toolserver.lab.net:9080/jenkins/job/test_prj/20/changes"&gt;809960&lt;/a&gt;</description>`and I tried sed -e 's/\&gt\;\(.*\)\&lt\;/\1/'` but didnt help

Comment: Please add your efforts to your question.

Comment: Also your comment seems contradictory to your post in terms of what pattern is wrapping the number you want to extract: is it `&gt;[NUMBER];/a&gt` or `>[number]</a>` ? Please clarify and edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ string='Build : 76.x-20161016_x_567.0 <br> GRN : <a href="http://toolserver.lab.net:9080/jenkins/job/test_prj/20/changes">109960</a>'

$ echo $string | sed 's/^.*>\([0-9]*\)<\/a>.*$/\1/'
109960
```